# Centering the links in my nav

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for a school project and I'm stuck. I made a nav bar for the website with links to other pages, one of these is a dropdown menu with more links. I want to center these links but I just can't do it, I have tried everythig I could find online and I'm lost. Could someone help me out?

This is the HTML code:

```
<nav>
  <h1 class="header"><span>A</span>2's Prachtige Website</h1>
   <ul class="ulnav">
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Intro en voorpagina.html"><span>I</span>ntroductie</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <li><button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"><span>O</span>mics Teksten</button></li>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <a href="../Omics/Metabolomics.html"><span>M</span>etabolomics</a>
            <a href="../Omics/Genomics.html"><span>G</span>enomics</a>
            <a href="../Omics/Transcriptonomics.html"><span>T</span>ranscriptonomics</a>
            <a href="../Omics/Epigenomics.html"><span>E</span>pigenomics</a>
            <a href="../Omics/Proteomics.html"><span>P</span>roteomics</a>
            <a href="../Omics/Systeembiologie.html"><span>S</span>ysteembiologie</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Key Gene.html"><span>K</span>ey Gene</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Vacatures.html"><span>V</span>acatures</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Interview.html"><span>I</span>nterview</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../HS Leiden.html"><span>H</span>S Leiden</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Bronnen.html"><span>B</span>ronnen</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
a.a-nav{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h1.header {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.ulnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
}

li.li-nav a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #269ccc;
    display: inline;
}

span {
  color: #ecbc00;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #269ccc;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #9ed2c5;
    color: white;
}
```

To anyone willing to help, thank you :)

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, anything whatsoever, don't hesitate to ask me :)

Comment: I dont see any dropdown menu?

Comment: Where you want `dropdown` position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question not too much clear but as my understanding, I think you want to achieve this. I hope it will help you.

```css
.dropbtn, a.a-nav {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

h1.header {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.ulnav {
    /*list-style-type: none;*/
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    padding: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    /*width: 90%;*/
    text-align: center;
}

li.dropdown, li.li-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #269ccc;
}

li.li-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
}

li.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    background: #269CCC;
    text-align: left;
    top: 27px
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 5px
}

span {
    color: #ecbc00;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #269ccc;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #9ed2c5;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1 class="header"><span>A</span>2's Prachtige Website</h1>
  <ul class="ulnav">
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Intro en voorpagina.html"><span>I</span>ntroductie</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"><span>O</span>mics Teksten</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="../Omics/Metabolomics.html"><span>M</span>etabolomics</a>
        <a href="../Omics/Genomics.html"><span>G</span>enomics</a>
        <a href="../Omics/Transcriptonomics.html"><span>T</span>ranscriptonomics</a>
        <a href="../Omics/Epigenomics.html"><span>E</span>pigenomics</a>
        <a href="../Omics/Proteomics.html"><span>P</span>roteomics</a>
        <a href="../Omics/Systeembiologie.html"><span>S</span>ysteembiologie</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Key Gene.html"><span>K</span>ey Gene</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Vacatures.html"><span>V</span>acatures</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Interview.html"><span>I</span>nterview</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../HS Leiden.html"><span>H</span>S Leiden</a></li>
    <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Bronnen.html"><span>B</span>ronnen</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey, it worked but it caused another problem (on my side at least), everything is centered but the dropdown menu is always on, you cant click it anymore

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot, whatever you did, it worked, all I had to do was add a few thing to fix the dropdown, thank you so so much :)
(and of course thanks to anyone else who helped out!)

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you want to achieve, but here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2gdr9d7/1/

```
nav ul { text-align: center; }
nav ul li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Add it to the bottom of your CSS.

Comment: I've tried text-allign: center; everywhere, it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok for lists then do these changes:

```
ul.ulnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

li.li-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Vovh6tNdIraEmdfdPPLN?p=preview

Comment: lol .. I dont agree. Table suck with responsiveness. Just stick with li.

Comment: Didn't know that, interesting

Comment: I'm very sorry but it doesn't seem to work, I alraedy tried text-align: center; Like everywhere you can imagine, thats the reason im stuck.

Comment: Right.. So what are you looking to solve here? What is wrong with the plnkr I linked you?

Comment: I'll link you an image, this is what it currently looks like;
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/241209724358492160/362943148059525122/unknown.png

Comment: What I want to do is center the elements in the nav bar, they are to the left, curretly

Comment: Yes and in my plnkr the elements are centered, so you must have some code that I don't have access to, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: If you want I can send you the whole file.
(also thank you so much for helping me)

Comment: That's ok. I would advice you to put your lists inside a <div> element and set that div's style like this: `<div style="text-align: center">your_lists</div>`. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it's helpful. Currently I have placed dropdown menu in first list item. So please place that ul to others where you want this.

```css
a.a-nav {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h1.header {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.ulnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  width: 90%;
}

li.li-nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #269ccc;
  display: inline;
}

span {
  color: #ecbc00;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #269ccc;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #9ed2c5;
  color: white;
}
li{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.dropdown{
  padding:0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  left: 0;
  background: #269ccc;
}
li ul.dropdown li a{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
li:hover ul.dropdown{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <h1 class="header"><span>A</span>2's Prachtige Website</h1>
    <ul class="ulnav">
      <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Intro en voorpagina.html"><span>I</span>ntroductie</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"><span>O</span>mics Teksten</button></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                       <a href="../Omics/Metabolomics.html"><span>M</span>etabolomics</a>
                       <a href="../Omics/Genomics.html"><span>G</span>enomics</a>
                       <a href="../Omics/Transcriptonomics.html"><span>T</span>ranscriptonomics</a>
                       <a href="../Omics/Epigenomics.html"><span>E</span>pigenomics</a>
                       <a href="../Omics/Proteomics.html"><span>P</span>roteomics</a>
                       <a href="../Omics/Systeembiologie.html"><span>S</span>ysteembiologie</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
          </ul>  
    </li>      
      <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Key Gene.html"><span>K</span>ey Gene</a></li>
      <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Vacatures.html"><span>V</span>acatures</a></li>
      <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Interview.html"><span>I</span>nterview</a></li>
      <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../HS Leiden.html"><span>H</span>S Leiden</a></li>
      <li class="li-nav"><a class="a-nav" href="../Bronnen.html"><span>B</span>ronnen</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

You can also check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khzw2fxe/1/)